# How can i calculate total quantity in xslt

Tags: xslt

I have a problem about counting quantity in foreach loop.

```
<xsl:for-each  select="//n1:Invoice/cac:InvoiceLine">
<xsl:variable name="result2" select="number(./cbc:InvoicedQuantity)"/> 
................
................
</xsl:for-each>
```

I want to assign sum of InvoiceQuantity and write one table cell. But I don't assign variable after define. How can i do sum process in foreach loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply do `<xsl:value-of select="sum(//n1:Invoice/cac:InvoiceLine/cbc:InvoicedQuantity)"/>` you output the sum directly, without needing a `for-each`.